# OpenXML how to make text bold

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, openxml

I use openXML to write a word document containing my text. Now I want to make a part of the text bold. I however fail to find a solution to make my text bold, since I can't figure it out. My code is:

```
        Dim FilePath As String = "C:\\MyFolder\\MyFile.docx"

        'Create a document to work in
        Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(FilePath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
        ' Add a main document part.
        Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()

        ' Create the document structure and add some text.
        mainPart.Document = New Document()
        Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
        Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
        Dim runNormal As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
        Dim runBold As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
        runBold.RunProperties.Bold()
```

I want to have two instances: one for normal text `runNormal` and one for the bold text `runBold`. Sadly the runBold does not work, while the runNormal works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out how it works, so here the solution for everyone:

If you are writing the first time in bold in your text, you need to use this:

```
Dim runProperties As RunProperties = run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
run.AppendChild(New Text("I am written in bold!"))
```

Now if you want to write again in bold, add this code:

```
run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
run.AppendChild(New Text("I am also written in bold!"))
```

That's it. To summarize, here the complete code:

```
Using wordDocument As WordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(DOCXPath, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)
' Add a main document part.
Dim mainPart As MainDocumentPart = wordDocument.AddMainDocumentPart()

' Create the document structure
mainPart.Document = New Document()
Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
' Write in bold (only works in the first line which you write)
Dim runProperties As RunProperties = run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
run.AppendChild(New Text("I am written in bold!"))
' If you want to write a second time in bold, just add the next line and afterwards your text to be written in bold.
run.AppendChild(New RunProperties(New Bold()))
run.AppendChild(New Text("I am also written in bold!"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following code.

```
WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(path, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document)

Dim mainDocumentPart As MainDocumentPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart()

mainDocumentPart.Document = New Document()

Dim body As Body = mainDocumentPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())

Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())

Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())

Dim runProperties As RunProperties = run.AppendChild(New RunProperties())

Dim bold As Bold = New Bold()

bold.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(True)

runProperties.AppendChild(bold)

run.AppendChild(New Text("Welcome!!!!!"))

doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save()
```

Comment: When I add this to my code, I am not able anymore to open my file since there are a few too much tags and I do not know from where they come. My file contains at the end the following part:  `<w:r><w:rPr><w:rPr><w:b /></w:rPr></w:rPr></w:r>`. After deleting this part I am able to open my .docx-file as usual.

Comment: Try the edited code and see if it helps.

Comment: This code works. I do have a question however: it is only the first line that is written in bold. My second line is written normal again. Isn't it possible to create two `run`, one in normal `runNormal` and the other one in bold `runBold`? And then when adding the text, I select either if it is written in bold or not?

Comment: Yes, only the format of one run in one Paragraph is specified in the sample code.
You can create two different runs in the same Paragraph to write in different formats.

Comment: Strangely when I do 2 paragraphs, it does not work and when opening the .docx-file I get an error: `Dim body As Body = mainPart.Document.AppendChild(New Body())
            Dim para As Paragraph = body.AppendChild(New Paragraph())
            Dim run As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
            Dim runBold As Run = para.AppendChild(New Run())
            Dim runBoldProperties As RunProperties = runBold.AppendChild(New RunProperties())
            Dim bold As Bold = New Bold()
            bold.Val = OnOffValue.FromBoolean(True)
            runBoldProperties.Append(bold)`